# dataTables - processing div hides before table is updated using fnReloadAjax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I am using [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) with server side processing enabled. While refreshing the table data using `fnReloadAjax()` method, the processing div shows up, then after request completes it hides(table still shows old data) and then after about 2 seconds new data appears in the table.

So there is a period of few second where it appears that the plugin has finished loading the new data but it still shows the old data.Is there a way to hold the processing div till the new data is drawn in the table?

Comment: you can use a loading image until new data is shown in the table

Comment: @MohitPandey I am already using an image. Its inside that processing div. I hoped that the plugin will behave properly or there is a possibility I am using it wrong. I can implement my own processing div, but was wondering if it can be done using the options of this plugin

Comment: When you look into the code of dataTable, you will notice that processing div is actually *processed* before drawing the table, I think that's why there's the delay issue here. There's [an extra API](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnProcessingIndicator) provided here that may be helpful to toggle processing div explicitly.

Comment: @RoyLing `_fnProcessingDisplay( oSettings, false )` is everytime called after `_fnDraw( oSettings )` in the datatables code. Can you point me where it is processed before drwaing the table. Maybe I could do something.

Comment: @anu check `_fnInitialise` function, after `_fnDrawHead` function is called, it's calling `_fnProcessingDisplay` there.

Comment: @RoyLing I found out that the problem is because of multiple requests. Can you suggest something on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478081/datatables-generating-multiple-server-side-requests)